# A detail in a proof of the Steiner's inequality about sets of finite perimeter

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

[image]

Given an open limited set $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary, how could I subdivide this set $E$ in a finite number of normal sets? I remind you that the normal set is a set of this form, given an open set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and two functions $\varphi_{1}$ and $\varphi_2$ defined on $A$ the corresponding normal set is $$\{(x,y) \in A : \varphi_{1}(x)<y<\varphi_{2}(x)\}.$$ Subdivide means to partition the set at most excluding $\mathcal{H}^{n}$ negligible sets.
My question emerges from a proof of the Steiner inequality that Francesco Maggi gives in this book at pag 161.
https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/sets-of-finite-perimeter-and-geometric-variational-problems/F8D0DABFFFB0D444C5AD5D37B3E3DBC1

What I know for certain is that I can choose a hyperplane $\Pi$
for which there are a $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}-$negligible amount of points with normal vector parallel to the hyperplane $\Pi.$ So almost all of the perpendicular lines to $\Pi$ are intersecting $E$ in a finite number of segments. In the figure I tried to give a sense of what I am asking.

Comment: I do not understand what is the question. Are you asking why you can approximate a finite perimeter set with sets with smooth boundary or are you asking how to subdivide a set with smooth boundary into finitely many "normal" sets?

Comment: @SonGohan sorry, I'm asking how to subdivide a set with smooth boundary into finitely many normal sets.

Comment: By the way, shouldn’t the normal set be defined as $A \times \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @SonGohan I am not great with definitions, but what I would like is to have a partitions of cylinders in which  each cylinder has as its bases the graphs of two smooth functions. I should find a way to insert a picture in my post, so that I could make it more clear. Sorry, I thought I had been more clear in the question. If it's not too much work, could you point out at least a feature of the post which makes the post unclear? I would like to receive a feedback. Tomorrow I will dedicate some time to find out how to insert images on my post.

Comment: @SonGohan if you are still interested in my question I inform you that I tried to be more clear in formulating my question.

Comment: Sure, i’ll give it a look asap